# Find $\int_\gamma{\dfrac{z}{\overline z}dz}$ where $\gamma$ is the border of $\{z: 1 < |z| < 2, Imz > 0\}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Find $\int_\gamma{\dfrac{z}{\overline z}dz}$ where $\gamma$ is the border of $\{z: 1 < |z| < 2, Imz > 0\}$. First of all, $\gamma$ is the border of a semiring (if I can call it so) so it must consist of two semicircles that have the same center and one has radius $2$ the other radius $1$. Then, I guess the integral can be split to integral over the bigger semicircle minus the integral over the smaller semicircle, because I think the directions of the curves must be different. Then the parametric representation of the semicircles will be $2e^{it}, 0 < t < \pi$ and $e^{it}, 0 < t < \pi$. But, from here on, if I solve the integral, I won't get the right result which should be $4/3$. What am I getting wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit: now, by placing the parametric function in $f(z)$ (the integrated function), then in both cases when integrating over $[0,\pi]$ I get $-2/3$. So I don't understand why the answer in the book is not negative, and also, the integral for both semicircles will be the same, so this means subtracting will make the answer 0, which is wrong, so I don't understand why I shouldn't be subtracting when I divide $\gamma$ into two semicircles.

Comment: The "border" you write is often called "boundary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the contour $\gamma$ is the counter-clockwise contour that is comprised of $(i)$ the straight line segment from $z=-2$ to $z=-1$, $(ii)$ circular arc $|z|=1$, $\arg(z)\in [0,\pi]$, $(iii)$ the straight line segment from $z=1$ to $z=2$, and $(iv)$ the circular arc $|z|=2$, $\arg(z)\in [0,\pi]$$.  Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_\gamma \frac{z}{\bar z}\,dz&= \int_{-2}^{-1} 1\,dx\\\\
&+i\int_\pi^0 e^{i3\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_1^2 1\,dx\\\\
&+i2\int_0^\pi e^{i3\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac43
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I was seeing it wrongly. I was taking the border of the ring and cutting it in two, so I wasn't seeing the linear parts

Comment: @H-a-y-K You're welcome.  My pleasure.